# How to log the content of csv in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following code

```
DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Employee.class);
from("file:src/main/resources/csv2?noop=true").routeId("route3").unmarshal(bindy).to("mock:result").log("${body[0].name}");
```

I am trying to log every line of the csv file, currently I am only able to hardcode it to print.

Do I have to use Loop even I don't know the number of lines of the csv ? Or Do I have to use processor ? Whats the easiest way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unmarshalling step is producing an exchange whose body is a list of tuples. For that reason you can simply use Camel splitter to slice the original exchange into 1-N sub-exchanges (one per line/item of the list) and then log each of these lines:

```
from("file:src/main/resources/csv2?noop=true")
.unmarshal(bindy)
.split().body()
.log("${name}");
```

If you do not want to alter the original message, you can use the wiretap pattern in order to log a *copy* of the exchange:

```
from("file:src/main/resources/csv2?noop=true")
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .wireTap("direct:logBody")
    .to("mock:result");

from("direct:logBody")
    .split().body()
    .log("Row# ${exchangeProperty.CamelSplitIndex} : ${name}");
```